# differentiate scenarios using XPATH

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I've the below cases.

```
**Case1:**
<para>1A/66</para>
<para>1A/34S/4</para>
<para>1/66</para>

**Case 2:**
<para>A/66</para>
<para>A1/1</para>
```

Here, the explaination is if the para starts with a letter (here it is `A`, it can be any alphabet), it should print `case 2` else it should print `case 1`.

please let me know how can i do this.

Here is a [DEmo](http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you have regular expression support so using e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="para[matches(., '^[a-zA-Z]')]">case 2</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para[matches(., '^[^a-zA-Z]')]">case 1</xsl:template>
```

Of course you can use a different regular expression to match on non-ASCII letters as well if "can be any alphabet" is meant to indicate other letters.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution, but this is not working if i use `text()` in place of `para`

Comment: And why do you want to use `text()` instead of `para`?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are :

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <xsl:call-template name="print-param" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*"/>
        </body>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "body">
        <!-- Match cases -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name = "print-param">
        <!-- Match cases -->
        **Case1:**
         <xsl:for-each select=".//para[matches(., '^[A-Za-z]\.*')]">
           <para><xsl:value-of select="." /></para>
         </xsl:for-each>
        **Case 2:**
         <xsl:for-each select=".//para[not(matches(., '^[A-Za-z]\.*'))]">
           <para><xsl:value-of select="." /></para>
         </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Check this [demo](http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cw)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution, but this is not working if i use `text()` in place of `para`

Comment: I did not get what you meant here : .. Is it it's output what you want ? .. Or may be you have to update your question ?!